# Contradictory proofs of $ax+by\ge{ay+bx}$ when $a\ge{b}$ and $x\ge{y}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification, fake-proofs

Here is a problem I found recently:

> If $a\ge{b}$,$x\ge{y}$, prove that $ax+by\ge{ay+bx}$ for all real numbers $a,b,x,y$.

I found $2$ solutions to the problem, which possibly contradict each other.

### Solution 1

We have $(a-b)\ge{0}$ and $(x-y)\ge{0}$. Multiplying them with each other, we have $$(a-b)(x-y)\ge{0}$$ $$\Rightarrow{ax+by}\ge{ay+bx}$$ as desired.

### Solution 2

There are several cases when for positive and negative $a,b,x,y$. We consider the case when $a,b$ are positive and $x,y$ are negative. Then we have $$ax\le{bx}\cdots(1)$$ $$ay\le{by}\cdots(2)$$ From $(1)-(2)$, we have $$ax-ay\le{bx-by}$$ $$\Rightarrow{ax+by}\le{ay+bx}$$

---

The above 2 solutions contradicts each other. Is there something wrong in my solutions?

***Note:*** *The question seems lame comparing it with other questions in MSE. But I'm a grade-4 student and I stucked at this question. So, please help me and ignore my mistakes*.

Comment: +1 for the way you explained the question. And welcome to MSE as a junior member.

Comment: In 2 you have a bad step.  From $ay \le by$ you incorrectly deduced $-ay \le -by$.  Congratulations.  Most grade 4 students do not know algebra.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. I just substracted (2) from (1). How I deduced $-ay\le{-by}$?

Comment: When you subtracted, it was equivalent to adding after sign reverse.  Subtracting won't work in general.  Example $10\gt 9$ and $9\gt 7$ would lead to $1\gt 2$.

Comment: But isn't that true- **if $a>b$ and $c>d$, then $a-c>b-d$ for all real numbers $a,b,c,d$**?

Comment: Why would $a,b > 0; x,y < 0$ imply $ax \le bx$ or that $ay \le by$?  Those would both be true if $a\ge b$ not otherwise. Also $M < N; J < K$ does not imply $M-H < N-K$.  If $J < K$ then $-J > -K$ and we have no idea how $M-J$ compares to $N-K$.

Comment: "But isn't that true- if a>b and c>d, then a−c>b−d for all real numbers a,b,c,d? "  Not at all!  Let $a =20$ and $b=19$ and $c = 7$ and $d = 1$ then $a-c = 13$ and $b-d =18$.

Comment: If $a > b$ then $a -c > b-c$ and $a-d > b-d$.  But we don't know how $a-c$ compares to $b-d$. We have $c > d$ so the number we are subtracting from big $a$ is larger than the number we are subtracting from little $b$.  If $c$ is much bigger than $d$ (bigger than $a-b$) our result will be smaller.  But if $c$ is not that much bigger than $d$ (smaller than $a-b$) the result will be larger.

Comment: tl; dr......   $a-c > b-d \iff a+d >b + c$.  We know $a > b$ and we know $c > d$ but we don't have *any* ideal how $a+d$ compares to $b+c$.  It is true that if $a >b$ and $c > d$ then $a+c > b+d$ because we are putting the heavier things on one side of a seesaw and the light things on the other.  Likewise if $a-d > b-c$ as we are subtracting a light thing from a heavy thing on the left and subtraction a heavy thing from a light thing on the right.  But we *can't* compare $a+d > b+c$ or $a-c> b-d$ because we have a light and heavy (or heavy minus light) on both side and no way to compare them.

Comment: Yes, I got it. @fleablood

Answer (score 1):

First method is flawless.

But the second you correctly that if $b \ge a> 0$ and $y \le x < 0$ then $ay \le by$ and $ax \le bx$

But when we says $1- 2$ implies..... you have no rule that if $M < N$ and $J < K$ that $M -J < N-K$.  As $J < K\implies -J > -K$ we have no way of comparing $M +(-J)$ to $N + (-K)$ when $M< N$ but $-J > -K$.

Indeed we actually have $ax - ay = a(x-y)$ and as $x-y > 0$ we have $a(x-y) \ge b(x-y) = bx -by$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I had some misconceptions.

Comment: It's okay.  If $A > B$ and $C > D$ we can have $A+C > B+D$ because we are putting the bigger things to one side and the smaller things to the other.  But we can *NOT* do $A-C > B-D$ because we we don't know if $A$ is bigger or smaller than $C$ nor by how much.  Nor do we know if $B$ is bigger or small than $D$ or by how much.